# trying to get this event through my function in swift XCode

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm looking to pass a event.keycode event through a function

I use this code:

```
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { //monitors which keys are pressed down.
        self.keyDown(with: $0)
        return $0
```

---

```
override  func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) { // Detects which keys are being hit.
                
        
       keydownlook().keyPressed("here")  <-- calling a function that is in another class

        
  }
```

I need to pass the event not just the result,
where it says here.
is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you can do this using closures:

```
class Test {
    var keyEventHandler: ((NSEvent) -> Void)?

    func keyPressed(event: NSEvent) {
        keyEventHandler?(event)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let test = Test()

test.keyEventHandler = { event in
    print(event)
}
```